# Dependency injected controllers in Play with @

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, playframework-2.4

This is not a blocking issue, but I would like to understand how Play handle controller injection better.

In [Play document about Routing in 2.4](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.2/ScalaRouting), it is said that:

> Play supports generating two types of routers, one is a dependency injected router, the other is a static router. The default is the static router, but if you created a new Play application using the Play seed Activator templates, your project will include the following configuration in build.sbt telling it to use the injected router:
>
> routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
>
> The code samples in Play’s documentation assumes that you are using the injected routes generator. If you are not using this, you can trivially adapt the code samples for the static routes generator, either by prefixing the controller invocation part of the route with an @ symbol, or by declaring each of your controllers as an object rather than a class.

So, to my understanding, with `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` in `build.sbt`, if I use `@` prefix for controller invocations, it is the same as making a controller as a singleton `object`. This goes against the fact that I have been declaring my controllers as `class` that has some injections (using `@Inject`), and I prefix all my controller invocations with `@` so that IntelliJ does not report error.

So, what does the `@` really do my the controller invocations?

Answer (score 4):

The `@` is an option for the `StaticRoutesGenerator`, it has nothing to do with the `Injected` one.

When you follow the recommended way with `InjectedRoutesGenerator`, your controllers **must** be a class, in which dependencies will be injected (automatically if you use runtime DI, or manually if you use compile-time DI). In the route file, you just have to reference the class without `@`.

If you choose the `StaticRoutesGenerator`, the router follows the same behavior as with Play 2.3 and lower. Controllers are by default object, and you can add a `@` to reference a class.

I hope this has addressed your concerns.

Comment: As of now what I have is my controllers as class, with injected components. I also have InjectedRoutesGenerator enabled in build.sbt. In my routes file, I have `@` prefix. And this is still working when I thougnt it should break. So I wonder in my current setup, if my controllers are injected.

Comment: What is you remove the `@`? I think they are just ignored with InjectedRoutesGenerators. And it's easy to know if your controllers are injected or not, just try to call them with a route. If it works, they are injected.

Comment: What do you mean "what is you remove the @?"

Comment: Calling a controller with a route as in `routes.Application.index`?

Comment: Now that you mention calling a controller, I did have some test that I use the application instance to create an injected controller. I think that means that my controllers are injected rather than static.

Comment: I wanted to say : "What if your remove the @? Does it still work ?" Like I've said, i think the @ does nothing with InjectedRouter. You can add a println is the controller class to see when it's created, and if the dependency are well injected. When you said "that my controllers are injected rather than static", do you mean "instancied" rather than "injected"? If it is your question, the controllers are instancied as a Singleton by default.

Comment: @JulienLafont There actually is a difference, as you an see [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/routes-compiler/src/main/scala/play/routes/compiler/RoutesGenerator.scala#L188).